# Grouping and summarising by a numeric and string factors in R not working

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I am trying to group by words but also by numbers (0 and 3). I want to then summarise the last column.
Below is a brief overview of my dataset:

```
  Word Delay Word_said
1  and     0         5
2  and     0         0
3  and     3         6
4 dont     0        14
5 dont     3         5
6 dont     3         8
7 what     0         5
```

and my expected output:

```
  Word Delay Avg_word_said
1  and     0             5
3  and     3             6
4 dont     0            14
5 dont     3           6.5
7 what     0             5
```

I have tried the following code

```
ZeroDelay <- Results %>% 
  select(c(Word, Delay, Word_said)) %>%
  group_by(Word) %>% 
  summarise(Avg_word_said = mean(Word_said))
```

and this outputs the following:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 2
   Word       Avg_word_said
   <chr>              <dbl>
 1  and                3.75
 2  and                7.25
 3  away               1   
 4  dont               8   
 5  dont               7.33
 6  dont               5.33
 7  how                6.56
 8 learning            4.62
 9  the                9.33
10  the                8   
11  what               7.64
12  when               6.5
```

(don't worry about the numbers being wrong and the extra words it is just a part of my big dataset)
But as you can see from the output above, it is don't fully grouping everything.

Even if I manually sorted the raw data into the groups I wanted, I then try and summarise it, it still comes out with the same output.

Thank you in advance but I am happy to elaborate on this if needed.

Comment: My expected output is the second dataframe in the question - I have just edited it in the question

Comment: Please check my solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we don't need the 0 values, either `filter` out or create the condition while `summarise`ing

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Word, Delay) %>% 
    summarise(Avg = mean(Word_said[Word_said != 0]), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  Word  Delay   Avg
#* <chr> <int> <dbl>
#1 and       0   5  
#2 and       3   6  
#3 dont      0  14  
#4 dont      3   6.5
#5 what      0   5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Word = c("and", "and", "and", "dont", "dont", 
"dont", "what"), Delay = c(0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 0L), Word_said = c(5L, 
0L, 6L, 14L, 5L, 8L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still the same problem but with different words have different categories, dont now has 5 etc

Comment: @ZacCotterell I checked your expected output and it is showing the same.

Comment: I'm going to try and get it online so you can look at it properly. Is there a good online IDE for R?

Comment: When somebody post an input and expected output and if the solution I am getting is matching the expected, then there is some issue in your structure.  Please use `dput`

Comment: How would you use `dput`. Sorry I have very new to R

Comment: @ZacCotterell Assuming that your input data object is `df1`, then use `dput(df1)` and copy/paste the output from the console to your post.  You will get similar structure output like in my post data

Comment: When I used you code, it worked fine for that example but not my whole dataset. What is the need to put the L at the end of the numbers?

Comment: @ZacCotterell it is just how integer values are represented in strcture to differentiate from numeric

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230909/discussion-between-zac-cotterell-and-akrun).